# How to calculate confidence interval for prediction

Tags: r, confidence-interval, prediction-interval

I have model with k = k0/(1+((distance/r0)^alpha)). I have parameter value for

- r0 =  0.019 with std.err = 0.0042
- k0 = 0.00605 with std.err = 0.00043
- alpha = 0.2608 with std.err = 0.0058 and
- distance = 0 to 5000

How can I calculate confidence interval for k in each distance? Can I use bootstrapping to calculate confidence interval for this? 
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean [tag:prediction-interval]s?

Comment: Are the standard errors independent?  (This is possible but unlikely.)  When they are not independent, you need information about their correlations.

Comment: I am not sure if the standard error is independent. I used mle2 (bbmle package) to estimate parameters and I got standard error from calculating the square root of the values on the diagonal of the inverse Hessian matrix. May you please explain more how I can find confidence interval from correlations?

Comment: The covariances are the rest of the values in the inverse Hessian. (The inverse Hessian at the optimum is returned by the `vcov` function.)